# Validation (): Attribute 'Factory' is not a valid attribute of element 'ServiceHost'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, service, factory

I'm getting

```
Validation (): Attribute 'Factory' is not a valid attribute of element 'ServiceHost'.
```

from VS2008 in an empty WCF Service Application after I add Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" to the @Service directive in the .svc file.  I've added System.ServiceModel.Web reference to the code-behind.

I'm at a total loss based on what I've read on MSDN.  Has anybody come across this before?

**Update:**

Factory doesn't even show up as an available attribute in the intellisense in the markup for the .svc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had .NET 3.5 installed but I didn't have SP1 installed for Studio 2008.  Ugh.

Comment: D'oh!  That'll do it.  Been there.  Done that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a reference to System.ServiceModel in the code behind.  Unless you have an explicit factory object, you don't need a reference to it.  I have a host in an IIS hosted service that looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Donaghe.ManualWCF.CalculatorService" %>
```

That's all you really need.  Make sure that what goes into the service attribute is the full name of your service class.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I do have a reference to System.ServiceModel in the code behind. 

And, I want to use WebServiceHostFactory so that I don't have to edit the web.config to set up the endpoints manually. I'm planning on hosting the service in IIS. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: And, yes I have the fully qualified name of the service specified.